# uploading image to db got an error in php

Tags: php, database

1. All is going fine but got this error
   `Notice: Undefined index: image in C:\wamp\www\neos-final\update-image.php on line 21`
2. Line 21 is `$image=$_FILES['image']['name'];`
3. What to do with this line :(

   ```
   <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="file" name="image" id="image" size="40">
   <input name="" type="submit" value="upload" />

   </form>
   <?php 
   $con = mysql_connect('localhost', '', ''); //Update hostname
   mysql_select_db("test", $con); //Update database name

   define ("MAX_SIZE","1000"); 
   function getExtension($str)
   {
        $i = strrpos($str,".");
        if (!$i) { return ""; }
        $l = strlen($str) - $i;
        $ext = substr($str,$i+1,$l);
        return $ext;
   }

   $errors=0;
   $image=$_FILES['image']['name'];
   if ($image) 
   {
       $filename = stripslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
       $extension = getExtension($filename);
       $extension = strtolower($extension);
       if ( ($extension != "jpg") && 
            ($extension != "jpeg") && 
            ($extension != "png") && 
            ($extension != "gif") && 
            ($extension != "JPG") && 
            ($extension != "JPEG") && 
            ($extension != "PNG") && 
            ($extension != "GIF") ) 
       {
           echo '<h3>Unknown extension!</h3>';
           $errors=1;
       }
       else
       {
           $size=filesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);

           if ($size > MAX_SIZE*1024)
           {
               echo '<h4>You have exceeded the size limit!</h4>';
               $errors=1;
           }

           $image_name=time().'.'.$extension;
           $newname="images/".$image_name;

           $copied = copy($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $newname);
           if (!$copied) 
           {
               echo '<h3>Copy unsuccessfull!</h3>';
               $errors=1;
           }
           else echo '<h3>uploaded successfull!</h3>';

           mysql_query("insert into list (image) values('".$newname."')");
       }

       //Display image
       $rs=mysql_query("select * from list");
       if($rs)
           while($row=mysql_fetch_array($rs))
           {
            ?>
            <img width="150" src="<?php echo $row['image'];?>"><br>
            <?php 
           }
   }
   ?>
   ```

Any idea?

Comment: You can Check DEveloper Tool to check what is being Posted on submit as it is because of undefined Veraible?

Comment: Why do you test `$extension` for uppercase strings when `strtolower` is applied?

Answer (score 1):

This notice `Notice: Undefined index:` comes when any index of array variable is not defined.

use `isset` here

```
if(isset($_FILES['image']))
{
    $image=$_FILES['image']['name'];
    //your rest of code here
}
```

Comment: Sir one more thing is...when I upload any image here it creates an id automatically say id = 0 in database and upload image..whereas I want the existing image to be replace with the new one?...can u pls check my code for this

Comment: @SwatiKanojia: If your updating the existing image then you need to pass `id` of the existing image as hidden value with form,by checking `id` you can update the image instead of creating new record.

Comment: Is there any simple code to do that...all these code sucks my mind :( dont knw what to do

Answer (score 0):

```
Use php isset()

if(isset($_FILES['image']))
{
  // your code 
}
```